# calling std::system with parameter containing space in double quotes

Tags: linux, c++11

I need to call a linux std::system call with parameter than contain string with spaces. In order to process it correctly using argc / argv I want to pass it with double quotes.

> std::string cmdline = "myprogram -d \"I am a sting\"" ;

if I cout this string I get good results.

When I send it to `std::system(cmdline)`
and look at ps -ef I get
myprogram -d I am a string

How can I keep "I am a string" as a single parameter for myprogram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem:

```
dlaru@IKH-LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/Users/dlaru
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
        std::string cmdline = "./see \"I am a string\"";
        std::cout << cmdline << std::endl;
        std::system(cmdline.c_str());
}

dlaru@IKH-LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/Users/dlaru
$ cat see.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        {
                std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }
}

dlaru@IKH-LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/Users/dlaru
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test

dlaru@IKH-LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/Users/dlaru
$ g++ -std=c++11 see.cpp -o see

dlaru@IKH-LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/Users/dlaru
$ ./test
./see "I am a string"
./see
I am a string
```

(tested in Cygwin)

Comment: looks like it works, I'm on debian, using g++, will test this program and let you know

Comment: Tested your program adding cin >>  at the end, and running ps -ef afterwards. You are correct - it works, for some reason ps -ef removes the "" from the string, but argv treat it as a single parameter.

Comment: @Dani I think why ´ps -ef´ dont show ´""´ is " itself is not a argument.